# Imagemagick - combining 'crop' and 'add layer' arguments

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have two commands that work fine:

```
convert Nord.png -gravity South -crop x80% -fuzz 50% -fill '#5BC236' -opaque '#8FBCBB' -background transparent -extent 800x800 out.png
convert Nord.png out.png -gravity Center -composite -background '#2E3440' -gravity Center -extent 3840x2160 background.png
```

What they do is that they take a PNG file like this:

[image]

And convert it to an image like this:

[image]

But in the process, a file like this is created:

[image]

I'm wondering if it's possible to combine these two commands, so that a) there's only one call to the `convert` command, and b) only one file is created as the output.

I tried this command,

```
convert Nord.png -gravity South -crop x80% -fuzz 50% -fill '#5BC236' -opaque '#8FBCBB' -background transparent -extent 800x800 out.png -gravity Center -composite -background '#2E3440' -gravity Center -extent 3840x2160 background.png
```

But the output is different:

[image]

How can I combine these two commands into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do some *"aside-processing"* in parentheses to clone the `Nord.png` image and make the crop and colour changes then when you exit the parentheses you will still have the `Nord.png` you started off with and the cloned, recoloured, resized image in the image stack which is how your second command starts anyway:

```
convert Nord.png \
    \( +clone -gravity South -crop x80% -fuzz 50% -fill '#5BC236' -opaque '#8FBCBB' -background transparent -extent 800x800 \) \
    -gravity Center -composite -background '#2E3440' -extent 3840x2160 background.png
```

The `-gravity Center` is a **setting** that gets remembered till you change it so there is no need to repeat it.